# Why is this UL and inline JS giving errors during HTML validation?

Tags: javascript, html, validation, w3c-validation

I've just run the homepage of a site I'm working on through the w3c HTML validator and it's come back with 3 errors and 2 warnings.  I've taken a look at them but can't see why they would be causing a problem.  I've pasted them in below (I've removed URL's/strings etc as the site isn't quite ready to be made public yet).  This is being validated against XHTML Transitional by the way.

The UL comes back with the following error: `end tag for "ul" which is not finished <ul id='tabs'></ul>`

```
<ul id='tabs'> 
<li> 
    <a href="/en/folder/folder/search?categories[]=cat1" class="tab1" title="tab_title">
        <img alt="img_alt" src="img_src" /> 
        <span> 
            tab1_text
        </span> 
    </a>
</li> 
<li> 
    <a href="/en/folder/folder/search?categories[]=cat2" class="tab2" title="tab_title">
        <img alt="img_alt" src="img_src" /> 
        <span> 
            tab2_text
        </span> 
    </a>
</li> 
<li> 
    <a href="/en/folder/folder/search?categories[]=cat3" class="tab3" title="tab_title">
        <img alt="img_alt" src="img_src" /> 
        <span> 
            tab3_text
        </span> 
    </a>
</li> 
<li> 
    <a href="/en/folder/folder/search?categories[]=cat4" class="tab4" title="tab_title">
        <img alt="img_alt" src="img_src" /> 
        <span> 
            tab4_text
        </span> 
    </a>
</li> 
<li> 
    <a href="/en/folder/folder/search?categories[]=cat5" class="tab5" title="tab_title">
        <img alt="img_alt" src="img_src" /> 
        <span> 
            tab5_text
        </span> 
    </a>
</li> 
<li> 
    <a href="/en/folder/folder/search?categories[]=cat6" class="tab6" title="tab_title">
        <img alt="img_alt" src="img_src" /> 
        <span> 
            tab6_text
        </span> 
    </a>
</li> 
<li> 
    <a href="/en/folder/folder/search?categories[]=cat7" class="tab7" title="tab_title">
        <img alt="img_alt" src="img_src" /> 
        <span> 
            tab7_text
        </span> 
    </a>
</li> 
<li> 
    <a href="/en/folder/folder/search?categories[]=cat8" class="tab8" title="tab_title">
        <img alt="img_alt" src="img_src" /> 
        <span> 
            tab8_text
        </span> 
    </a>
</li> 
</ul>
```

For the inline javascript, I'm getting 2 errors and 2 warnings all for the same thing - I have a simple if statement with && and the validator appears to be seeing this as HTML rather than javascript: `character "&amp;" is the first character of a delimiter but occurred as data` and `xmlParseEntityRef: no name`

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    if (weather_data != null && weather_data['data'] != null){
    display_weather();
}
</script>
```

The javascript is placed just before the body close tag at the end of the document.
If you need to see the full source then let me know and I can send it over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML doesn't support intrinsic CDATA so [ampersands have special meaning](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.8) in XHTML that they don't have in HTML, but you are probably serving your XHTML as text/html so see the compatibility guidelines for [Embedded Style Sheets and Scripts](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/#C_4)

As for:

> end tag for "ul" which is not finished

given

```
<ul id='tabs'></ul>
```

A list has to at least one list item in it. I'm guessing that you are populating it with JavaScript (hence your second example of a `ul`), but the validator doesn't care about that.

Comment: Hi David, the UL I've given above is the exact one that the validator is complaining about - I just copied and pasted it from the View Source in Chrome but removed the strings.  I admit the tabs UL is empty for some pages so I'll need to resolve that, but for the page in question it is populated by the server before being sent.

Comment: Ah, forget about that - I forgot we have it setup so the full page can only be viewed from a specific IP address!  So when the validator goes to check it it's only seeing part of the page where the tabs UL is empty. Doh!

Comment: You could try something like this: `<ul><li style="display:none"></li></ul>` - the validator would work and no one would see the placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the UL problem, but you might want to put CDATA around your script.

see http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp

Answer (score 0):

To validate the inline Javascript, you need to wrap the contents in CDATA tags, and add JS comments, to make it validate:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
if (weather_data != null && weather_data['data'] != null){
  display_weather();
}
//]]>
</script>
```

I checked the HTML list fragment you posted in the W3C validator and it validated successfully as *HTML 4.01 Strict* and *XHTML 1.0 Strict*. So the problem is somewhere else. Can you post a link to your entire page?